# What causes an Infinite loop when using put() vs putAll()

Tags: java, hashmap, infinite-loop

In the simple example code below, I wanted to quickly put the HashMap 'additional' into the payload of the Process object. However, I noticed that when I used .put() in order to nest the data deeper behind an additional key value("exampleData"), an infinite loop occurs:

```
public class Process {

    public Map<String, Object> getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(Map<String, Object> payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    Map<String, Object> payload;
}
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process process = new Process();
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        linkedHashMap.put("uuid", "uuid");
        process.setPayload(linkedHashMap);
        Map<String, Object> additional = new HashMap<>();
        additional.putAll(process.getPayload()); //additional.put("exampleData", process.getPayload());
        process.getPayload().put("additionalData",additional);
    }
```

When the code is executed with putAll(), no infinite loop occurs and the Process object looks like this:

[image]

However, when using put() instead of putAll(), an infinite loop occurs, with the payload containing itself and a StackOverFlowError occurs:

[image]

What is causing this infinite loop and why is putAll() immune to it?

Comment: There shouldn't be a `StackOverFlowError`...

Comment: Well, I forgot to add, the StackoverFlowError occurs when I try to retrieve data from the Process payload(when using .put() instead of putAll()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line:

```
additional.put("exampleData", process.getPayload());
```

`additional` now has a reference to the process payload. The relevant object graph looks like this:

```
process ---> payload <---- additional
```

(arrows represent references)

Then you did:

```
process.getPayload().put("additionalData",additional);
```

which adds to the payload, a new reference pointing to `additional`. Notice how this creates a cycle:

```
process ---> payload <---- additional
                |               ^
                |_______________|
```

This is fine, until you try to print the contents of `payload`. One of its values is `additional` so the contents of `additional` needs to be printed too, and one of `additional`'s values is `payload`, so the contents of payload is printed again, and the loop continues... Unfortunately, the person who wrote the `toString` method for `Map` hasn't written anything to detect this.

[`putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) on the other hand,

> *Copies* all of the mappings from the specified map to this map.

Therefore, `additional.putAll(process.getPayload());` does not make `additional` have a reference to `payload`. Instead, it just adds whatever keys and values payload has, to `additional`.

In addition, it will also not create a cycle if you create a new map that has all the keys and values of payload, and add it to `additional` using `put`.

```
additional.put("exampleData", new HashMap<>(process.getPayload()));
```

Rather than having a reference to `payload`, additional would have a reference to a new map:

```
process ---> payload        additional ----> a copy of payload
                |               ^
                |_______________|
```